# Force MySQL Shutdown

Tags: mysql

We have MySQL 5.1.45 running on a RedHat box.  We needed to shut the box down for maintenance last week and had an issue.

We first closed down all connections.
Then we ran the MySQLAdmin/shutdown command.
The database appeared to hang.  We waited for 30 minutes before trying Ctrl-C which gave us an error and we had to end up physically cycling the box.

Most of the documentation I can find points to InnoDB problems, but we are using MyISAM.

Is there a better way to shut down MySQL than running the Shutdown command?
Is there a way to force MySQL to shut down when it appears to hang?

Comment: I think you might find better answers at Serverfault or Superuser for this kind of question.

Comment: You are probably right.  I am so used to coming here for dev answers If forgot about their other products.

Answer (score 1):

`service mysql stop` ?  I'm not so sure though...